# Прямая речь?

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли оформить высказывания в приведенном предложении таким образом?

Например, вместо «нет, мы не дадим Вам больничный» Вы можете сказать «да, я Вас понимаю, и в то же время мы не имеем права оформить больничный без определенного диагноза».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не вижу, почему нельзя. 
Вопрос об уместности и удачности построения фразы решается в зависимости от контекста и ситуации вообще.

Answer (score 0):

Можно обойтись без лишних слов. Например, так: "Мы не имеем права оформить больничный без определенного диагноза"

Comment: Дык оно, конечно, можно...
Только тут что-то типа инструкция для тренинга персонала. 
Как с клиенту вежливо зубы заговаривать.  
Вопрос не в том, что и как сказать, а как эту инструкцию написать.